# Why am I not allowed to propose a tag synonym ?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tag-synonyms

Why am I not allowed to propose a tag synonym on Super User? I have 10k+ rep, the privileges show 100% across all - what am I missing out on ?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems I forgot reading about:

> one of the requirements for proposing a synonym is that you have to have a score of <s>10</s> 3 or more in that tag.

via [Brandon](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/74022/brandon) on [Meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69263/why-am-i-not-allowed-to-propose-a-tag-synonym/69267#69267)

Comment: I don't recall seeing that before either...hmmm... oh well, +1 for telling me something new.

Comment: Seems it stops you even *voting* on a synonym if you don't meet the criteria - for example there's a suggested one for [amazon-ec2] at the moment, which after a quick test I can say I am unable to vote upon (having no answers in that tag).

Comment: @DMA57 - this was apparently changed yesterday http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64247/show-synonym-suggestions-awaiting-my-vote/69190#69190