# Drop the score requirement for proposing tag synonyms

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-synonyms

Related to : [Why am I not allowed to propose a tag synonym ?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1653/why-am-i-not-allowed-to-propose-a-tag-synonym)

Couple of days ago, there were certain changes done to the requirements of [who can propose synonyms.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64247/show-synonym-suggestions-awaiting-my-vote/69190#69190)

> So you need a **score of 10 or more on answers for the tag**, to participate in the tag synonym creation process (proposal and voting)

I'm getting real annoyed by those <strike>stupid</strike> synonym proposal changes.

Latest example: 
[`[Popups]`](https://superuser.com/tags/popups) ( 33 questions ) v/s [`[Popup]`](https://superuser.com/tags/popup) ( 2 questions ).

So I went over to propose a synonym.

[image: But NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO!]

Now either I let it remain as it is, or I have to go and manually retag them. And that means bumping the questions up. 
When there's a rep requirement, I don't know why in the world there's a score requirement. I realize that more the score == better participation in the tagged questions.

This makes sense for Stack Overflow, or ( perhaps ) Server Fault, but this is counter-productive in Super User.

The third option is to raise a question in Meta and ask a question and wait for a Moderator or some one else who has sufficient score in those tagged questions ( hmm .. any way to find out WHO exactly? ) to propose and vote for it.. This just makes no sense - considering that the whole point of synonyms was to reduce the manual editing and bumping up.

Comment: Perhaps you should take this to Meta-SO also.

Comment: @Nifle [Done](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69588/drop-the-score-requirement-for-proposing-tag-synonyms-atleast-for-super-user). Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Ground control to Major Tom

Comment: @yoda receive you loud & clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jeff has since implemented the following solution:

> I improved the error message and dropped the requirement down to 3 score. Ultimately I think this req should scale to the # of questions in the tag.

[Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69588/drop-the-score-requirement-for-proposing-tag-synonyms-atleast-for-super-user/69661#69661)

Comment: Yes, I noticed. I've mentioned my thoughts over there.