# Tags: google-desktop and google-desktop-search

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I believe the two tags, [google-desktop](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-desktop) and [google-desktop-search](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-desktop-search) should be synonyms as they are one and the same product: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Desktop

Comment: I would have have, if I could but [this](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1660/drop-the-score-requirement-for-proposing-tag-synonyms) prevents me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[google-desktop](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-desktop) has now been proposed as a synonym for [google-desktop-search](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-desktop-search).